# Usage of Provide and Deliver

Tags: meaning

I have a question for using two verbs "Provide" and "Deliver" to this sentence:

> Company provides electricity

or:

> Company delivers electricity

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Both verbs can be correct, but they emphasize different aspects of how the electrical grid works.

The verb “provide” means, “make available for use,” and this is exactly what the electric company does. They provide electricity so that customers can use that electricity. As one company says on its [website](https://www.mge.com/about-mge/who-we-are/service-area.htm):

> MGE provides electricity to 151,000 customers.

The verb “deliver” means, “bring or transport something to a destination,” and we could also think of electricity being “delivered”. In fact, one [website](https://www.eia.gov/energyexplained/index.php?page=electricity_delivery) explains:

> Electricity is delivered to consumers through a complex network.

However, I would add one note: your versions are a little scant as standalone sentences:

> Company provides electricity.

We’d typically expand on that a little bit, perhaps by adding a determiner before the word *company*, and then maybe adding some more content, such as:

> Our company provides electricity to consumers all across the province.

Comment: Agreed; “our company” or “the company” is preferred.